# Mimic the iPhones phone keypad input

Tags: iphone, ios

How would you go about mimicing the iPhones keypad input. So that when you click one 1 is displayed then 2 then it is 12... so on and so forth along with the ( ) -. I don't want to use the actual phone app because I'm creating a false dialer, but I want it to look and function kind of like the actual thing.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated thanks.

EDIT:

Ok so I put in all the buttons needed but I ended up making them all individual buttons. THey are all linked including the label and this is what one button and the updater looks like.

```
-(IBAction)zeroButton:(id)sender{
self.enteredPhoneNumberString = [self.enteredPhoneNumberString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", "0"]];
[self updateFormattedPhoneNumberLabel];

}

-(void)updateFormattedPhoneNumberLabel {
    if ([self.self.enteredPhoneNumberString length] > 3) {
        NSString *firstThree = [self.enteredPhoneNumberString substringToIndex:2];
        NSString *lastSet = [self.enteredPhoneNumberString substringFromIndex:2];
        self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@", firstThree, lastSet];
    }
    else if ([self.self.enteredPhoneNumberString length] > 7) {
        NSString *firstThree = [self.enteredPhoneNumberString substringToIndex:2];
        NSString *secondThree = [self.enteredPhoneNumberString substringToIndex:2];
        NSString *lastSet = [self.enteredPhoneNumberString substringFromIndex:2];
        self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@-%@", firstThree, secondThree, lastSet];
    }
}
```

I had also tried it with the "" not being around the numbers being appended. Any idea why nothing is being displayed?

NEW EDIT:

I added enteredPhoneNumberString = @""; and with the numbers formatted the way you original had it displays the numbers. The main issue I'm having now is getting it so that the () and - pop up in the right spots.

Comment: Edited my response to maybe help you with formatting the display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest creating a grid of `UIButton`s that mimics the numpad, these buttons all call a method such as `keyPadButtonTouchedUpInside:(id)sender` and have a tag that corresponds to the number it represents.

Implementation of `keyPadButtonTouchedUpInside:(id)sender` may look like...

```
- (void)keyPadButtonTouchedUpInside:(id)sender {
    UIButton *touchedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    if (touchedButton.tag <= 9) {
         self.enteredPhoneNumberString = [self.enteredPhoneNumberString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", touchedButton.tag]];
         [self updateFormattedPhoneNumberLabel];
    } else {
         // maybe some other code for pounds/stars entered on the keypad if you have these
         // you will also be checking if the user hit the backspace key and trim your
         // phone number string by 1
    }
}
```

Now you need to implement `updateFormattedPhoneNumberLabel`

This will look at the instance NSString variable `self.enteredPhoneNumberString` and update a UILabel that you have in place to display the number.

`updateFormattedPhoneNumberLabel` might look like...

```
- (void)updateFormattedPhoneNumberLabel {
    if ([self.self.enteredPhoneNumberString length] > 3) {
         NSString *firstThree = [self.enteredPhoneNumberString subStringToIndex:2];
         NSString *lastSet = [self.enteredPhoneNumberString subStringFromIndex:2];
         self.formattedPhoneNumberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@", firstThree, lastSet];
    } else if .... 
      // more conditions to check for other lengths of the 
      // entered number and continue with the proposed formatting methods.
```

Hopefully that gets you down the path, there may be more efficient methods for doing this but in reality its not an intensive operation so I wouldn't worry to much about optimization unless you see some kind of entry lag which I wouldn't expect.

**EDIT**

I would probably update the formatting conditions so that the formatting happens in the following behavior.

1-3 numbers entered shows as "1", "12", or "123"

4-7 numbers entered shows as "123-4", "123-45", "123-456", or "123-4567"

8-10 numbers entered show as "(123) 456-78", "(123) 456-789", or "(123) 456-7890"

11 numbers entered show as "1+(234)-567-8901"

Anything more than 11 I would just show a string of numbers, unless you want to get into formatting non-us numbers. You should also play around with entering numbers in the Phone App to see how it responds if you want to mimic it completely.

Comment: `stringByAppendingFormat:` might be a little neater, but +1 in any event.

Comment: @Chris Wagner So I added it (I placed what I did up above) I'm not sure why by not text is being displayed in the label when I click the number buttons. Any idea why?